# The Plank Problem 2 Dimensions

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

We were trying to solve this wonderful problem, but have not succeeded to solve.

It goes like this:
Let $R=[0,1]^2$, and $D\subseteq R$ be a convex set which intersects each side of $R$. Define a plank to be a set of the kind $[a,b]\times[0,1]$ or $[0,1]\times[a,b]$. The planks are parallel to the axes. Show that for each set of planks that covers $D$, it holds that the sum of the areas of the planks is at least 1.

Thanks,
LLAP.

A hint from the oracle: The Marriage theorem. (We still have yet to solve)

Comment: Would you be happy with a solution that does not use Marriage Theorem?

Comment: Yes, it is also ok.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As promised, here is a geometric solution, without "Marriage Theorem" (I also would like to see a solution which uses it).

*A remark concerning probabilistic methods.*: I do not think that the Lebesgue measure on $R$ is the right object here, since **$D$ can have Lebesgue measure zero** (if $D$ equals a diagonal of $R$). I do suspect however that there is a proof using a non-Lebesgue measure on $R$ which detects "widths" of subsets rather than their areas (see my comment on George Lowther's proof). However, I do not know how to construct one (at least, without first proving Theorem 1).

Below is my solution almost completely rewritten (I originally missed two cases).

I will label the vertices of $R$ as $a=(0,0), b=(0,1), c=(1,1), d=(1,0)$.  By the "width" of a plank I mean the length of its shorter side. I let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ denote the projections of $R$ to its horizontal side $ad$ and vertical side $ab$ respectively.

Theorem 1. For every finite collection $C$  of planks covering $R$, the total width $W$ of $C$ is $\ge 1$.

Proof. The proof is by induction on the total number $N$ of planks. If $N=1$, it is clear that $W\ge 1$.

Now, consider the case $N=2$, when $C$ consist of one vertical plank $P$ and one horizontal plank $Q$ of the widths $v$ and $w$ respectively. (The case $N=2$ with just two horizontal or two vertical planks reduces immediately to $N=1$.)

Lemma 1. If $N=2$ then $W=v+w\ge 1$.

Proof. Since $D$ intersects all four sides of $R$, consider the quadrilateral $D'=x_1y_1x_2 y_2\subset D$ where $x_1\in ad\cap D, x_2\in bc\cap D', y_1\in ab\cap D', y_2\in cd \cap D$. The planks $P$ and $Q$ break edges of $R$ in subsegments of the lengths $g_1, g_2$ and  $h_1, h_2$, see figure below.  I will consider only the *critical case* depicted in the figure, where the segments $y_1x_2, x_2y_2, y_2x_1, x_1y_1$ pass through the four intersection points $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ of the boundaries of planks (if this is not the case, one can modify $D'$, $P$ and $Q$ so that the total width of $P$ and $Q$ strictly decreases and they still cover $D'$).

Consider the shaded rectanges as in the figure: Rectangles marked with the same color have the same area. The total area of the four shaded rectanges adjacent to the corners of $R$ equals 
$$
(h_1+h_2)(g_1+g_2)= (1-v)(1-w). 
$$
On the other hand, the area of the rectange $z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4$ equals $vw$ and, clearly, the total area of the shaded rectangles inside  $z_1 z_2 z_3 z_4$ equal $(1-v)(1-w)$. From this, we get
$$
(1-v)(1-w)\le vw
$$
$$
1\le v+w=W,
$$
as claimed. qed.

[image]

Now, let $N\ge 3$ and assume that for each collection of $<N$ planks, $W\ge 1$. I will now consider only collections of planks where each plank is different from the entire $R$ (otherwise, the claim is clear).

Consider a collection $C$ of planks which consists of $m$ vertical planks $P_i$ and $n$ horizontal planks $Q_j$, where $m\le n$ (otherwise we swap the vertical and horizontal coordinates) and $N=m+n\ge 3$. I number the vertical planks $P_i$ from left to right. Without loss of generality, we can assume that vertical planks are pairwise disjoint and horizontal planks are also pairwise disjoint (otherwise, we amalgamate the non-disjoint vertical/horizontal planks, without increasing the total width $W$ and reducing the number of planks). 
For the same reason, we can assume that any proper subset of $C$ does not cover $D$.

The complement
$$
D\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^m P_i
$$
is a union of convex sets $D_j$. I also number $D_j$'s from left to right. Each $D_j$ is covered by exactly one horizontal plank (by the disjointness property). Hence, the number $k$ of the convex sets $D_j$ is $\le n$. Furthermore, $k\in \{m-1, m, m+1\}$ since there exists exactly one $D_j$ between each consecutive pair $P_i, P_{i+1}$. Since $m\le n$, it follows that at most one of the planks $Q_i$ covers two different components $D_j$, which means that
$$
k-1\le n\le k. 
$$
By combining these inequalities, we see that
$$
m\le k\le m+1,
$$
and, hence, either $P_1$ or $P_m$ does not contain one of the two vertical sides of $R$. (I assume that it is $P_1$ which does not contain $ab$, otherwise, we change the orientation.) Lastly, if $k=m$ (i.e, $P_m$ contains $cd$) then $n=k=m$ and, hence, each plank $Q_i$ covers exactly one of the components $D_j$. In any case, I let $Q_1$ denote the horizontal plank covering $D_1$.

**Case 1:** $k=n$, i.e., each $Q_i$ covers exactly one $D_i$, $i=1,...,n$. As we noted above, 
the  component $D_1$ has nonempty intersection with the vertical segment $ab$. Let $h_1$ denote the length of the projection $\pi_2(D_1)\subset ab$  and let $v_1$ denote the length of the projection $\pi_1(D_1)$ of $D_1$. Since $D_1$ is covered by a $Q_1$, it is clear that width of $Q_1$ is $\ge h_1$.

Lemma 2. $v_1\le h_1$.

Proof. Consider a point $x\in D_1\cap ab$ and the segment $yz=D_1\cap P_1$. The triangle $\Delta=xyz$ is contained in $D_1$. Moreover, convexity of $D$ and the fact that it intersects all four sides of $R$ imply that the rays from $x$ extending the segments $xy$ and $xz$ both intersect the union of the horizontal segments $bc\cup da$. It is then an elementary geometric calculation to conclude that the height $v_1$ (from the vertex $x$) of $T$ is $\le $ the length of the base $yz$ of $T$. The latter is $\le h_1$. qed.

Let $P_0\subset R$ denote the vertical plank which is the product $\pi_1(D_1)\times ab$ ($P_0$ is not a part of our collection $C$ of planks). By Lemma 1, the width of $P_0$ is $\le$ the width of $Q_1$.
 Then replace $Q_1$ with $P_0\cup P_1$. Since $Q_1$ covers only the component $D_1$, it follows that the new collection $C'$ of planks still covers $R$. By Lemma 1, $C'$ has overall width $W'\le W$ and, by construction, $C'$ consists of $N-1$ planks. Therefore, by the induction assumption, $1\le W'\le W$ and we are done. This concludes the proof of Theorem 1 in Case 1.

**Case 2:** $n=k-1$. Then $k=m+1$, $n=m$.

**Subcase 2a:** $Q_1$ covers $D_1$ and (after renumbering if necessary) a distinct horizontal plank $Q_n$ covers $D_{n+1}$. Then we repeat the argument from Case 1 and conclude that $W\ge 1$.

**Subcase 2a:** $Q=Q_1$ covers both $D_1$ and $D_{n+1}$. We then switch roles of horizontal and vertical directions (this is OK since $n=m$).  Repeating the above case-by-case analysis we conclude that there exists a vertical plank  $P:=P_\ell$ which covers two components $E_1, E_{n+1}$ of
 $$
 R\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n Q_i. 
 $$
 The components $E_1, E_{n+1}$ have nonempty intersections with the horizontal sides of $R$. 
 Now, pick from each subset $D_1, D_{m+1}, E_1, E_{n+1}$ one point $y_1, y_2, x_1, x_2$ which belongs to a side of $R$.

Lemma 3. The convex hull $D'$ of $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$ is covered by the planks $P$ and $Q$.

Proof. It suffices to show that every edge of $D'$ is contained in $K=P\cup Q$. Suppose that there exists an edge of $D'$ (after relabeling, we can assume that this edge is $x_1y_1$) which is not contained in $P\cup Q$. 
Let $x_1'\in x_1y_1$ and $y_1'\in x_1y_1$ be the points of intersection of the boundary of $K$ with $x_1y_1$  (these intersection points are labelled so that $x_1'$ belongs to the left side $s_1$ of $P$ and $y_1'$ belongs the bottom side $t_1$ of $Q$. Let $z_1'=s_1\cap t_1$; then the solid right angled triangle $x_1'y_1'z_1'$ is not covered by $P\cup Q$. However, by the disjointness property of planks, if follows that a small corner of $x_1'y_1'z_1'$ at the vertex $z_1'$ is not covered by any plank in $C$.

[image]

Contradiction. qed.

In view of Lemma 3, we can now apply Lemma 1 (since we have a covering of $D'$ by two planks) and conclude that the total width of $P$ and $Q$ is $\ge 1$.

This concludes the proof of Theorem 1. qed

I gave a proof of Theorem 1 for finite collections of planks. An easy approximation argument implies that the same conclusion holds for countable collections of planks. (For uncountable collections, the statement is meaningless, as far as I can tell.)

Theorem 1 is a special case of much harder theorem (theorem 2 below) proven by T.Bang in

*[A solution to the "Plank Problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2031721)"*, Proceedings of AMS, 2 (1951).

The "Plank Problem" itself was posed by A.Tarski in 1932.

Theorem 2: Let $D\subset R^d$ be a bounded convex subset and $C$ is a countable collection of planks covering $D$. Then the *total width* of $C$ is $\ge$ the *width* of $D$.

Here are the definitions: A *plank* in $R^d$ is the closed region bounded by two parallel hyperplanes. The width of a plank is the distance between the hyperplanes. The total width of $C$ is the sum of width of planks in $C$. The width of $D$ is the infimum of lengths of its orthogonal projections to straight lines in $R^d$.

Bang's proof is clever and nonelementary. It has led to a number of problems some of which are still open. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_plank_problem) to find more about it.

Comment: I added a note to my proof which should answer your concern with the probabilistic method.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative proof, using a probabilistic 'coupling' method, via the following Lemma. Throughout, I let $D$ be as in the question: a convex subset of $R=[0,1]^2$ intersecting each of the four sides of $R$.

> **Lemma**: There exists random variables $U_1,U_2$ (defined on some probability space) which are both uniform on $[0,1]$, and such that $(U_1,U_2)$ lies in $D$ with probability 1.

*[Note: Although $U_1$ and $U_2$ here have the uniform distribution, there is no requirement for the joint distribution of $(U_1,U_2)$ to be uniform, or even have an absolutely continuous distribution. For example, if $D$ Is one of the diagonals of the unit square, which has zero Lebesgue measure but satisfies the requirements, then we would take $U_1=U_2$ (or $U_1=1-U_2$). This ensures that $(U_1,U_2)\in D$ and, if $U_2$ is chosen with the uniform distribution, then $U_1$ is also uniform.]*

If $A\subseteq[0,1]$ is the set of $x$-coordinates of the vertical planks, then it is a finite union of closed intervals, the vertical planks cover the region $A\times[0,1]$ and have total area $\lambda(A)$ ($\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure). Similarly, if $B\subseteq[0,1]$ is the set of $y$-coordinates of the horizontal planks then they cover the region $[0,1]\times B$ and have total area $\lambda(B)$. The following corollary of the above lemma is then a positive answer to the original question.

> **Corollary**: If $A,B$ are measurable subsets of $[0,1]$ such that $D\subseteq(A\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times B)$, then $\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)\ge1$.

*Proof*: Letting $U_1,U_2$ be random variables uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ with $(U_1,U_2)\in D$ (almost surely),
\begin{align}
\lambda(A)+\lambda(B)&=\mathbb{P}(U_1\in A)+\mathbb{P}(U_2\in B)\\
&\ge\mathbb{P}(U_1\in A{\rm\ or\ }U_2\in B)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\left((U_1,U_2)\in(A\times[0,1])\cup([0,1]\times B)\right)\\
&\ge\mathbb{P}\left((U_1,U_2)\in D\right)\\
&=1.
\end{align}

---

I'll give a proof of the lemma now, which will require going through several cases. Letting $\pi_i\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ ($i=1,2$) denote projection onto the $x$ and $y$ coordinates respectively, $\pi_i(x_1,x_2)=x_i$, we need to find a random variable $X$ taking values in $D$ such that $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_2(X)$ are both uniform on $[0,1]$. The lemma will then be answered by taking $U_i=\pi_i(X)$.

I'll make repeated use of the fact that if $X$ is uniformly distributed on one of the diagonals of a rectangle $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]$ then $\pi_i(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[a_i,b_i]$. The idea is to find a finite set of rectangles $R^{(k)}=[a^{(k)}_1,b^{(k)}_1]\times[a^{(k)}_2,b^{(k)}_2]$ and numbers $p^{(k)}\ge0$ summing to $1$ such that each $R^{(k)}$ has a pair of opposite corners in $D$ (and, by convexity, a diagonal in $D$), then we can choose $X$ to be uniformly distributed on the diagonal of $R^{(k)}$ with probability $p^{(k)}$. Then, $U_i=\pi_i(X)$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[a^{(k)}_i,b^{(k)}_i]$ with probability $p^{(k)}$, so has probability density
$$
p_i(x)=\sum_kp^{(k)}(b^{(k)}_i-a^{(k)}_i)^{-1}1_{\{a^{(k)}_i < x\le b^{(k)}\}}.
$$
I'll do this so that the probability density is $1$ on $(0,1]$.

First, let $P_1=(x_1,0)$, $Q_1=(0,y_1)$, $P_2=(x_2,1)$ and $Q_2=(1,y_2)$ be points of intersection of $D$ with the edges of $R$. Then, the quadrilateral $P_1Q_1P_2Q_2$ is contained in $D$.

By symmetry, we suppose that $x_1\le x_2$, $x_1\le y_1$. There are a few cases to consider (I include diagrams, with the shaded area being the convex hull of the points $P_1,Q_1,P_2,Q_2$, which is contained in $D$, and the red lines are the rectangle diagonals supporting the distribution of $X$).

[image: plots of cases]
**Case I:** $y_1\ge y_2$

In this case,the four rectangles with diagonals $P_1Q_1$, $Q_1P_2$, $P_2Q_2$, $Q_2P_1$ do not intersect. Together with the center rectangle, $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$, which is contained in $D$ they partition $R$. Explicitly, the rectangles $[0,x_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $[0,x_2]\times[y_1,1]$, $[x_2,1]\times[y_2,1]$, $[x_1,1]\times[0,y_2]$ and $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_2,y_1]$ partition $R$ and each have a diagonal in $D$. So, we can choose $X$ to be uniformly distributed on a diagonal of any these rectangles with probability equal to the area of the rectangle.

In the remaining cases, the rectangles with diagonals $Q_1P_2$ and $Q_2P_1$ overlap, so the construction in Case I does not work.

**Case II:** $x_1\le y_1\le x_2\le y_2$. In this case $P_1Q_1$ is the diagonal of a rectangle which is taller than in is wide. We add a rectangle to the right of this to make a square, and take diagonals of these. Similarly, we add a rectangle below the one with diagonal $P_2Q_2$ to make a square, and take diagonals of these. These two squares do not overlap, so we can add the line segment in $D$ joining the nearest corners of these squares (which is a diagonal of the square $[y_1,x_2]^2$). More explicitly, using 'BL-TR' to mean 'bottom-left to top-right diagonal', etc.

- $R^{(1)}=[0,x_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $p^{(1)}=x_1$ (TL-BR = $P_1Q_1$ is in $D$).
- $R^{(2)}=[x_1,y_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $p^{(2)}=y_1-x_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(3)}=[y_1,x_2]\times[y_1,x_2]$, $p^{(3)}=x_2-y_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(4)}=[x_2,1]\times[x_2,y_2]$, $p^{(4)}=y_2-x_2$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(5)}=[x_2,1]\times[y_2,1]$, $p^{(5)}=1-y_2$ (BR-TL = $P_2Q_2$ is in $D$).

**Case III:** $x_1\le y_1\le y_2\le x_2$. This is a similar arrangement to Case II except that the rectangle with diagonal $P_P2Q_2$ is taller than it is wide, so we add a rectangle to the left of this rather than below to make a square.

- $R^{(1)}=[0,x_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $p^{(1)}=x_1$ (TL-BR = $P_1Q_1$ is in $D$).
- $R^{(2)}=[x_1,y_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $p^{(2)}=y_1-x_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(3)}=[y_1,y_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$, $p^{(3)}=y_2-y_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(4)}=[y_2,x_2]\times[y_2,1]$, $p^{(4)}=x_2-y_2$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(5)}=[x_2,1]\times[y_2,1]$, $p^{(5)}=1-x_2$ (TL-BR = $P_2Q_2$ is in $D$).

**Case IV:** $x_1\le x_2 < y_1 < y_2$. In this case, any two squares (with standard orientation) containing diagonals $P_1Q_1$ and $P_2Q_2$ overlap, so the construction in cases I and II does not work.

The point $(x_2,y_1)$ is in $D$, and there exists unique $a_0\in[0,y_1]$, $b_0\in[x_2,1]$ such that $(x_2,a_0)$ and $(b_0,y_1)$ are on $Q_2P_1$. Explicitly, $a_0=y_2\frac{x_2-x_1}{1-x_1}$ and $b_0=y_2^{-1}(y_1+x_1(y_2-y_1))$.
Choosing $a\in[a_0,y_1]$ and $b\in[x_2,b_0]$, so that $(x_2,a)$ and $(b,y_1)$ are in $D$, take

- $R^{(1)}=[0,x_1]\times[0,y_1]$, $p^{(1)}=x_1$ (TL-BR = $P_1Q_1$ is in $D$).
- $R^{(2)}=[x_1,x_2]\times[0,a]$, $p^{(2)}=x_2-x_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(3)}=[x_2,b]\times[a,y_1]$, $p^{(3)}=y_1-x_2$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(4)}=[b,1]\times[y_1,y_2]$, $p^{(4)}=y_2-y_1$ (BL-TR is in $D$).
- $R^{(5)}=[x_2,1]\times[y_2,1]$, $p^{(5)}=1-y_2$ (BR-TL = $P_2Q_2$ is in $D$).

It can be seen that using this distribution, $U_2=\pi_2(X)$ is uniform on $[y_1,1]$ with probability $1-y_1$ and is uniform on each of $[0,a]$ and $[a,y_1]$. The probability of $U_2$ being in $[0,a]$ is $x_1\frac{a}{y_1}+(x_2-x_1)$. For $U_2$ to be uniform on $[0,1]$ we need to solve $x_1\frac{a}{y_1}+(x_2-x_1)-a=0$. It can be checked that this is negative for $a=a_0$ and positive for $a=y_1$, so it can be solved for some $a$ in $[a_0,y_1]$. Explicitly, $a=y_1\frac{x_2-x_1}{y_1-x_1}$. Similarly, choosing $b=(y_2-x_2)^{-1}(y_1+x_2(y_2-y_1-1))$ gives the uniform distribution for $U_1=\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: This is interesting, although it will take me some time to digest the argument. Can you define a "new" finitely additive measure on subsets of the square, whose value on each convex subset is the min of its vertical and horizontal widths? Maybe this is what you are secretly doing. Existence of such measure immediately implies the positive answer to the problem.

Comment: No, that's not what I am doing. I added a bit more detail, and a note clarifying that the distribution of $(U_1,U_2)$ need not be absolutely continuous (in fact it never is with my constructions).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!